# How can I setup my Netbeans IDE for making Java ME applications?

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, java-me

Ok, I have Netbeans 6.7.1 installed with the default Java SDK. I'm using Linux Mint.

Now I'm told that I have to download [Java Platform Micro Edition Software Development Kit 3.0](http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/index.jsp)

So, **should** I download this? And once I download and install this in Linux, what do I have to install for Netbeans so I can create a Mobile Application? I'm fairly new to this environment so please any advice is welcome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have Java installed (version >= 6 ) and then simply go to: http://netbeans.org/downloads/ and download the version that comes with JAVA ME support. Then install it, and you are ready to go :)

And no, you shouldn't download JAVA ME SDK 3.0 since it is not supported in linux. *sigh*

While at it I'd recommend you to read also the links below:
Also if you're just getting started here are some nicely written tutorials with examples:

- http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/02/09/j2me1.html
- http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/05/03/midletUI.html
- http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/07/07/j2me3.html
- http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/09/27/j2me4.html

Answer (score 1):

I think this only applies if you download a version without JavaME modules. If you download the version with JavaME modules, you don't have to do this. The provision is to allow you to install multiple versions of the emulator (including Nokia's) and work with them.

If you have downloaded a version of NetBeans without ME, then do this
1. Download the JavaME SDK and install that eg. /opt/java/javame
2. Install ME modules in NetBeans. Tools -> Plugins -> Installed and activate JavaME
3. Add the SDK in NetBeans Tools -> Java Platforms -> Add Platform -> Java ME Platform Emulator  and follow the instructions

I'm using NB 6.8 BTW.

Answer (score 1):

In NetBeans, go to the "Tools/Plugins" menu, then in the "Available plugins" tab, select the plugins which are part of the "Java ME" category. now click "instal"... NetBeans will take care of downloading, installing and configuring everything for you.